# Creating something similar to 'Show Touches' option in Dev Options

Tags: java, android, view, touch

I am trying to build something for my app that does essentially the exact same thing as the 'Show Touches' Option does in Dev Settings on the newer android versions.

When a person touches the screen when in the app, a small circle should appear directly below their finger and follow it around the screen.

I have the circle appearing and following the finger. The problem I'm having is that my circle is a view, and when I try putting another view (in my case a GridView) in the app, it covers my circle view. So you can interact with the GridView but I think the circle view is hidden behind, or overwritten.

In my case I need something like the touch view on top, but still being able to interact with views below. Basically exactly like Show Touches except specifically in-App.

My Code for the circle:

**MainActvity.java**

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

drawingView dview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dview = new drawingView(this);
    dview.bringToFront();

    setContentView(dview);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1);

            GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                    Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, "Position " + position,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity1, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**drawingView.java**

```
public class drawingView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

static int x, y, r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
final static int radius = 30;
Paint paint;

public drawingView(Context context) {


    super(context);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setARGB(255, r, g, b);

    setFocusable(true);

    this.setOnTouchListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    paint.setARGB(255, r, g, b);

    x = (int) event.getX() - (radius / 2); 
    y = (int) event.getY() - (radius / 2);
    randColor();
    invalidate();

    int eventaction = event.getAction();
    switch (eventaction) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        /*r = 111;
        g = 111;
        b = 111;*/
        paint.setARGB(1, r, g, b);

        break;
    }


    return true;

}

public void randColor() {
    r = 1;
    g = 1;
    b = 1;
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  tools:context=".Activity1" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is much appreciated,

**EDIT** I refreshed all the code above to reflect @Onurs Answer, and to show the Grid code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `onDraw`, use [`draw`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29).

```
@Override 
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
}
```

Comment: sorry, that doesn't seem to change anything. I've posted all of my code up if that helps